# UNITY CS1061 Sprite does not contain definition for enabled

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am following a tutorial on 2048 in unity. He is using a Text and Image to render his 'tiles' and I decided to use a sprite because I have pre-made tiles in adobe. The first bit of code is the TileStyleHolder and the second script is called Tile(to be attached to the actual sprite/image itself that will be enabled/disabled.)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class TileStyle 
{
    public Sprite tile_number;
}

public class TileStyleHolder : MonoBehaviour
{
    //SINGLETON
    public static TileStyleHolder Instance;

    public TileStyle[] TileStyles;

    void Awake() 
    {
        Instance = this;
    }
}
```

AND THIS IS THE SECOND SCRIPT~~

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Tile : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int Number 
    {
        get 
        {
            return number;
        }
        set 
        {
            number = value;
            if (number == 0)
                SetEmpty();
            else 
            {
                ApplyStyle(number);
                SetVisible();
            }
        }
    }
    private int number;

    private Sprite TileSprite;

    void Awake() 
    {
        TileSprite = transform.Find("numcell").GetComponent<Sprite>();
    }

    void ApplyStyleFromHolder(int index) 
    {
        TileSprite = TileStyleHolder.Instance.TileStyles[index].tile_number.ToSprite();
    }

    void ApplyStyle(int num) 
    {
        switch (num) 
        {
            case 2:
            ApplyStyleFromHolder(0);
            break;

            case 4:
            ApplyStyleFromHolder(1);
            break;

            case 8:
            ApplyStyleFromHolder(2);
            break;

            case 16:
            ApplyStyleFromHolder(3);
            break;

            case 32:
            ApplyStyleFromHolder(4);
            break;

            case 64:
            ApplyStyleFromHolder(5);
            break;

            case 128:
            ApplyStyleFromHolder(6);
            break;

            case 256:
            ApplyStyleFromHolder(7);
            break;

            case 512:
            ApplyStyleFromHolder(8);
            break;

            case 1024:
            ApplyStyleFromHolder(9);
            break;

            case 2048:
            ApplyStyleFromHolder(10);
            break;

            case 4096:
            ApplyStyleFromHolder(11);
            break;

            default:
            Debug.LogError("Check the numders that you pass to ApplyStyle");
            break;
        }
    }

    private void SetVisible() 
    {
        TileSprite.enabled = true;
    }

    private void SetEmpty() 
    {
        TileSprite.enabled = false;
    }


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: yes you can't .. a sprite is an asset. You rather want to enable/disable the Component/GameObject using that sprite ... please add you complete code

Comment: **Stop** Please **[EDIT](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58102896/edit)** your question and add all your relevant code there. Format it using the `{ }` button!

Comment: ok, fixed it i hope that is clear

Comment: Yes way better ;) `Sprite` is not a component so you can't use `GetComponent<Sprite>` As said you have to find the component using that sprite like e.g. `SpriteRenderer` or `Image` and enable/disable that instead

Comment: Sorry about the messed up format!! And thank you! I will get right to it!

Comment: After fixing this issue, I receive cannot convert sprite renderer to sprite... I've changed it in different ways to avoid it, but no luck. what am i missing?

Comment: The question is what are you trying? How/Where does this `Sprite` come from? Where is it used? What is the expected behavior you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using an `Image` component you can reference the sprite with:

```
Sprite mySprite = GetComponent<Image>().sprite;
```

If you're using a `SpriteRenderer` componenent you can reference the sprite with:

```
Sprite mySprite = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite;
```

Comment: this. this saved me. I just got through a huge portion because of this, thanks so much!